# REGEX: Cut string on different parts knowing words length

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string:

```
const str = '0x60c980600b6000396000f360208060008037602181600080600261fffff136602014167faf92e7b2c77d83eaf65cbf5ab7415c4eddfd900eab716dcd6c43d5cd998c32a6602151141660505736156400611cfbfc421116608d57fe5b7f8c1d64e3bd87387709175b9ef4e7a1d7a8364559fc0e2ad9d77953909a0d1eb360206000a173578c86b36a7694d4eafc88c4ac8efb369b5317a8ff5b7f5d26862916391bf49478b2f5103b0720a842b45ef145a268f2cd1fb2aed55178600080a1739a54cb6a479023658cea01425e8035e4df93f925ff'
```

And i want to cut it on parts first word have legnth of 74 symbols, 2nd have length of 64 symbols etc.

My regex looks like:

`\b\w{1,74}\w{1,64}\w{1,22}\w{1,10}\w{1,94}\w{1,40}\w{1,80}\w{1,40}\w{1,20}\b`

but it doesn't work. I manage to do it with slice and substring but it's very ugly and want to use regex. How to make the regex to cut specific parts of the string knowing word length

Comment: If you want to extract something, you'll need to add capture groups using `(...)`

Comment: I would only use regex, if you don't have the exact cut positions.

Comment: if the length are known and constant, use rather `slice(startIndex, endIndex)`

Comment: you'd also use `{74}` not `{1,74}` since you "know" the word length (your example is 18 characters short of what you "know"

Comment: @Cid - that's what they ARE using and find it ugly (as would I)

Comment: `(\w{1,74})(\w{1,64})(\w{1,22})(\w{1,10})(\w{1,94})(\w{1,40})(\w{1,80})(\w{1,40})(\w{1,20})` This one seems to do the trick cheers just 1 more question, i have empty string at the start and the end of the match why like this?

`'AAAAstringToSplitAAAA'.split(`(\w{1,74})(\w{1,64})(\w{1,22})(\w{1,10})(\w{1,94})(\w{1,40})(\w{1,80})(\w{1,40})(\w{1,20})`)` and the result have empty stirngs on first and last place I can filter them but prefer to fix the pattern any ideas?

Comment: please put code in the question

Comment: ```
const regex = /^(\w{1,74})(\w{1,64})(\w{1,22})(\w{1,10})(\w{1,94})(\w{1,40})(\w{1,80})(\w{1,40})(\w{1,20})$/

const string = '0x6....5ff'

string.split(regex) => ['', correctResult, correctResult, '']
```

How to remove this empty strings without filter  (fix the pattern)

Comment: please put code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you know about string slicing.

```
const str = '0x60c980600b6000396000f360208060008037602181600080600261fffff136602014167faf92e7b2c77d83eaf65cbf5ab7415c4eddfd900eab716dcd6c43d5cd998c32a6602151141660505736156400611cfbfc421116608d57fe5b7f8c1d64e3bd87387709175b9ef4e7a1d7a8364559fc0e2ad9d77953909a0d1eb360206000a173578c86b36a7694d4eafc88c4ac8efb369b5317a8ff5b7f5d26862916391bf49478b2f5103b0720a842b45ef145a268f2cd1fb2aed55178600080a1739a54cb6a479023658cea01425e8035e4df93f925ff';
var word_len = [74, 64, ...];
var temp = 0;

for (int i=0; i<=word_len.length; i++) [
    console.log(str.slice(temp, word_len[i]+1); // Or you can also append to another list
    temp = word_len[i]+1;
}
```

I don't know much about JavaScript, But i think you get it what i'm trying to say

Answer (score 0):

A simple, easy way, no regex needed

```js
const str = '0x60c980600b6000396000f360208060008037602181600080600261fffff136602014167faf92e7b2c77d83eaf65cbf5ab7415c4eddfd900eab716dcd6c43d5cd998c32a6602151141660505736156400611cfbfc421116608d57fe5b7f8c1d64e3bd87387709175b9ef4e7a1d7a8364559fc0e2ad9d77953909a0d1eb360206000a173578c86b36a7694d4eafc88c4ac8efb369b5317a8ff5b7f5d26862916391bf49478b2f5103b0720a842b45ef145a268f2cd1fb2aed55178600080a1739a54cb6a479023658cea01425e8035e4df93f925ff';

function cutIt(str, cuts) {
  const x = str.split('');
  return cuts.map(l => x.splice(0, l).join(''))
}
const result = cutIt(str, [74,64,22,10,94,40,80,40,20]);
console.log(result);
```